# Prevent overlapping labels on the X-axis with ggpubr (ggline function)

Tags: r, axis-labels, ggpubr

I have a plot that has 7 different variables on the X axis. Unfortunately, all these 7 variables have quite long names:

```
1 Amsterdam_Center       
2 Amsterdam_Nieuw_west    
3 Amsterdam_Noord        
4 Amsterdam_Oost        
5 Amsterdam_West          
6 Amsterdam_Zuid          
7 Amsterdam_Zuidoost
```

I would like to have my plot to have clearly readable labels on the X-Axis. However, when I write my code all the labels on the x-axis overlap so nothing is readable:

```
ggline(only_price_district, x = "neighbourhood_cleansed", y = "price_difference",
       add = c("mean_se", "jitter"),
       ylab = "District", xlab = "Price difference")
```

As I want to save this plot as a pdf, this needs to be fixed. Does anybody have any tips on how I can change my code to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: Honestly, each label begins with "Amsterdam", so why not exclude that portion of each label?  Shorter labels are not likely to overlap.  Perhaps something in a title would indicate these are all Amsterdam locations.

Comment: Yes, in this scenario I could remove the Amsterdam part but that will not always work. So this is maybe a bad example from me. However, what if the labels are completely different and cannot be shortened. Is there a way possible to still make them readable?

Comment: You could reduce the size and/or angle of the text in ggplot within the `element_text(color, size, face, family, angle, hjust, vjust)` within the `theme()`.  Also you could insert newline `\n` if you have multiword lables, etc.